# Not able to call angular service from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs and trying to learn it. I have create three different js files for a vanilla application They are

**loginBoot.js**

```
var LoginBoot = (function(module,$,angular,global){
    console.log("Initializing Logging Application");
    _appName  = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).getAttribute('ng-app');
    _app = angular.module(_appName,[]);
    $.extend(module,{
        appName:_appName,
        app:_app    
    });
    return module;
}(LoginBoot ||{},this.jQuery,this.angular,this));
```

**loginService.js**

```
 var LoginService = (function(module,$,angular,global){
        console.log("Initializing Login Service");
        var app = LoginBoot.app;
app.service('GetLoggingCredential'['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
                         this.sayHello = function(){
                             console.log("Saying Hello");
                         };        
                }]);
        $.extend(module,{
        });
        return module;
    }(LoginService || {},this.jQuery,this.angular,this));
```

**loginController.js**

```
var LoginController = (function(module,$,angular,global){
    console.log("Initializing Login Controller");

    var app = LoginBoot.app;
    app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http,GetLoggingCredential){
        $scope.getUser = function(){
            GetLoggingCredential.sayHello();
        };
    }]);
    $.extend(module,{
    });
    return module;
}(LoginController || {} ,this.jQuery,this.angular,this));
```

I am trying to invoke the service on a button click through this controller.

```
<button type="button" id="loginSubmit" ng-click="getUser()"/>Click Here</button></div>
```

But this is throwing an error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined**

I am following javascript module pattern for organizing my code. Any help will be truly appreciable

Answer (score 1):

`app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http,GetLoggingCredential){`

should be,

`app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', 'GetLoggingCredential', function($scope,$http,GetLoggingCredential){`

You didn't add `GetLoggingCredential` as the dependency in the array

Comment: Doing so is throwing a new error !
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- GetLoggingCredential

Comment: @VaskarRayKarmakar Because there is no `$scope` associated with a service… Please begin with some tutorials to learn AngularJS.